# How to save a copy of current excel to CSV to new folder?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am trying to save my current excel called Gaf to a CSV.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Workbooks(GAF).Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A2").Value & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

Any help?

Or.......

```
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\User\Test.CSV" & Test1Str & " " & TestStr & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

Technically works but not exactly a CSV FILE...  I have tried putting in ".csv", xlCSV
FileFormat:=xlCSV also gives me errors.

Comment: What is the error that you are facing?

Comment: `Workbooks(GAF).Sheets(Sheet1)` Is `GAF` a variable? If it is the name of the workbook then it has to be in double quotes. Similarly the case with `Sheet1` like `Workbooks("GAF").Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: I'm not sure this should be closed: people make this mistake quite often, but the title should be something like "How to reference a sheet properly" so searches bring users here, and @SiddharthRout's answer should be front and center

Comment: Honestly I tried all that and it only gave me a error 9 instead.  Apparently 'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FileFolder & (FileName + " " + newName + "-" + Lpad(CStr(i), "0", 2)) & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV' Works.  Maybe if I fiddle around with that I can get it working.  Here's hoping...

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Marthinus.csv", fileformat:=6 Works great.  But it completely ignores your macro and saves the original document to a new area without any changes as a csv

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry for all responses but another could be         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="FileDIrectory heret" & Test1Str & " " & TestStr & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Name fileformat:=6.  Yet to get any working apart from the earlier comment but there is a huge problem with that as it ignores changes you made.

Comment: @SiddharthRout ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\User\Test.CSV" & Test1Str & " " & TestStr & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Name works but not as a CSV.  I believe if I edit this code slightly I should be able to get it working.  Only errors thus far

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Test" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV.  This almost did the trick.  But the changes are not applied to the CSV file at all.

Comment: Hmm CSV does not seem to like highlighted data or tables. This is a problem indeed...

Comment: If your book has may sheets, then occurr error.  csv file has a  only one sheet.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783923/excel-macro-multiple-sheets-to-csv/44792295#44792295) example convert  multiple sheets to csv files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of many codes to converting excel sheet to csv.

```
Sub test()
    Dim WB As Workbook, csvWB As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim myPath As String, myFn As String
    Dim vDB
    myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    myFn = myPath & "test.csv"

    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set WS = WB.ActiveSheet
    vDB = WS.UsedRange

    Set csvWB = Workbooks.Add(Template:=True)
    With csvWB
        Sheets(1).Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
        .SaveAs myFn, xlCSV
        .Close (0)
    End With

    Set csvWB = Nothing


End Sub
```