# Saving Single Sheet as CSV File

Tags: vba, excel

I am new at VBA and I have tried to do some research on this topic but with no luck. I have a workbook with multiple sheets but I only want to save sheet 6 as a CSV file to a certain location without opening a new file. How would I go about that using VBA linked to something like a button? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *"without opening a new file"*? You can use `Sheet6.SaveAs "foo.csv", xlCSV` but this will become your currently edited document and the old one will close. You want to keep the original workbook open dont you?

Comment: Yes I am trying to save the one sheet as a CSV file to upload to a database. But i am not wanting to close the original workbook. I dont want a book 2 to open as a CSV file. I want it to save under the same name but have like a - CSV

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783923/excel-macro-multiple-sheets-to-csv/44792295#44792295) is applying to multi sheets. you can work well only one sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Create a button and link it to this macro:

```
Sub Sheet6ToCSV()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False:  Application.EnableEvents = False:  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  On Error GoTo Cleanup

  Dim fold As String: fold = "C:\SO\"
  Dim fName  As String: fName = "MySheet6"

  Worksheets("Sheet6").Copy
  With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs fold & fName
    .Close False
  End With

Cleanup:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True:  Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```