# stop excel adding extra quotes

Tags: excel

in excel I want to save in CSV format these 2 cells:
abc, "def"

excel adds extra quotes so I get: abc, """def"""

expected result: abc, "def"
what would be the easiest way for it (I don't want to run 'replace' afterwards or any macros. I'm looking for automatic solution in one step).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should do it with vba.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783923/excel-macro-multiple-sheets-to-csv/44792295#44792295)

This is a slight modification.

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim xcsvFile As String
    Dim rngDB As Range

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
        xcsvFile = CurDir & "\" & Ws.Name & ".csv"
        With Ws
            r = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            c = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
            Set rngDB = .Range("a1", .Cells(r, c))
        End With
        TransToCSV xcsvFile, rngDB

    MsgBox ("Files Saved Successfully")
End Sub

Sub TransToCSV(myfile As String, rng As Range)

    Dim vDB, vR() As String, vTxt()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
    Dim objStream
    Dim strTxt As String

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    vDB = rng
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        n = n + 1
        ReDim vR(1 To UBound(vDB, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            vR(j) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve vTxt(1 To n)
        vTxt(n) = Join(vR, ",")
    Next i
    strTxt = Join(vTxt, vbCrLf)
    With objStream
        '.Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText strTxt
        .SaveToFile myfile, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Sub
```