# Programming data in Excel to string to workbook to CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to create a VBA where I input information regarding payments across 22 columns. These columns include payment amount, account, etc. I can then run a macro and it formats the data to a usable string, then exports the data to a CSV file. The data has to be formatted with apostrophe's and commas between the info.

For example, column B is merchant ID and column C is merchant name (Column A is blank).  I type 123 in column B and xyz in column C. It gets converted to '123','xyz', ... , ..., The goal is to have the formatting completed, concatenated and then exported to a CSV. Currently I'm using a mix of formulas/functions and a macro.

I use formulas to get to the formatting correct by using:   ="'"&B2&"'"&"," 
Then use concatenate to merge all 22 rows to a single string

Then I recorded a macro with the following:

```
    Sub BCM_CSV_export()
'
' BCM_CSV_export Macro

    Range("B21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""'""&R[-19]C&""'""&"","""
    Range("B21:V21").Select
    Selection.FillRight
    Range("B21:V30").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Selection.FillDown
    Range("B40").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCAT(R[-19]C:R[-19]C[20])"
    Range("B40:B49").Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Workbooks.Add
    Windows("BCM CSV Workbook.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("E13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "CSVDate.csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B21").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-24

End Sub
```

The code seems to work on my laptop. The CSV file shows up in 'My Documents'. But my colleague encounters errors. The code doesnt seem to run.

My question is 2 fold:
1. Is there something inherently wrong with my macro that it only runs on my laptop?
2. Is there a way to convert the 22 rows of data into a single text string and into a new CSV workbook without the intermediate steps of my using the text string formatting and concatenate function?

I used the search function and didnt see anything exactly matching this. Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: [`.Select`/`.Activate`/`Selection`/`ActiveCell`/`ActiveSheet`/`ActiveWorkbook` etc... should be avoided.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718179/1422451)

Comment: refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783923/excel-macro-multiple-sheets-to-csv/44792295#44792295)

Comment: "my colleague encounters errors" - maybe ask them *what* errors they see?  That could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to check the two lines of codes:

```
   Windows("BCM CSV Workbook.xlsm").Activate

   Windows("Book1").Activate
```

Maybe your colleague don't have the name of worrkbook BCM CSV Workbook.xlsm and Book1 opened