# Filename based on value cell,but with specific format

Tags: excel, vba

i want to save a filename based on a cell value (AA2 for example) which has date format (dd/mm/yyyy) but i want it to be like yyyymmdd without slash (/). This code works fine but gives me the current date (which doesnt help)

```
Sub CopyToCSV()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFileName As String
'The path and file names:
MyPath = "C:\Hello"
MyFileName = "Greetings_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
'Makes sure the path name ends with "\":
If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
'Makes sure the filename ends with ".csv"
If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then Hello = Hello & ".csv"
'Copies the sheet to a new workbook:
Sheets("final step").Copy
'The new workbook becomes Activeworkbook:
With ActiveWorkbook
'Saves the new workbook to given folder / filename:
    .SaveAs Filename:= _
        MyPath & MyFileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False, _
        Local:=True
'Closes the file
    .Close False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `MyFileName = "Greetings_" & Format((Range("AA2").Value, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"`

Comment: I tried it but even the cell AA2 is not empty, excel name stops at Grretings_

Comment: If the cell you need isn't on the ActiveSheet then you need to specify which sheet you want to take the date from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```vb
Sub CopyToCSV()
    Const MY_PATH As String = "C:\Hello\"
    Dim MyFileName As String, dt As Date
    
    dt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("info").Range("AA2").Value '<< specify sheet name
    MyFileName = MY_PATH & "Greetings_" & Format(dt, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("final step").Copy
    
    With ActiveWorkbook 'The new workbook becomes Activeworkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
            CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Another issue fro the above code. I cant find out got to make this csv with utf8 encoding. Seems in 2016 excel doesnt work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49399803/478884